# Inserting multiple rows in temp table without loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

This question has already been asked several times but the solution is not working for me. I don't know why.

Actually i am trying to create a temp table in sql query where i am inserting some records in temp table using select into but everytime it returns empty row:

here is what i am trying:

```
    Create Table #TempTable
  (
      EntityID BIGINT
  )

    INSERT INTO #TempTable (EntityID)
    SELECT pkEntityID  FROM Employee  WHERE EmpID = 45

    Select * from #TempTable
```

Corresponding to 45 , there are 10 rows in Employee table. IS it like I have to do something else or a loop like structure here as we can only insert one row in a table at once?

Comment: Are you sure `SELECT pkEntityID  FROM Employee  WHERE EmpID = 45` returns 10 rows?

Comment: Your query is fine.  No rows match the condition `EmpId = 45` . . . or you are making a mistake when you check the rows in `#TempTable`.

Comment: yes. i am sure. it will always return multiple rows and i have to collect all the ids in a table to join it with another table.

Comment: try dropping `WHERE EmpID = 45`. I think there must be a mistake.

Comment: Unless pkEntityID is the wrong data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been stated in the comments, all of which i up-voted, but to answer your question... there isn't anything else you have to do. There clearly isn't an `EmpID = 45` in your source table. Here's a reproducible example:

```
Declare @Employee Table (pkEntityID bigint, EmpID int)
insert into @Employee (pkEntityID, EmpID)
values
(32168123,45),
(89746541,45),
(55566331,45),
(45649224,12)


Create Table #TempTable
    (
    EntityID BIGINT
    )

INSERT INTO #TempTable (EntityID)
SELECT pkEntityID  FROM @Employee  WHERE EmpID = 45

Select * from #TempTable

drop table #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you accidentally also created the Employee table in the master database and you are currently connected to the master database?